# Checking whether the browser is HTML5 compliant before deciding the type of the input field

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

Say I have some JavaScript code which looks like this:

```
 function CheckDateField()
    {
    if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
        $(function () {
            $(".datefield").datepicker();
        });
    }
    }
```

This checks if the version of the browser is HTML 5 compliant and uses a date field if so; else a text field.

My .NET Core view has a field like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DOB" class="control-label"></label>
                @*@Html.TextBox("datepicker")*@
                @Html.TextBox("datepicker", null, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

How do I use the field in the JavaScript? I have tried this:

```
<label asp-for="DOB" class="control-label" onload="CheckDateField()"></label>
```

It would be good to put the JavaScript directly in the lavel if possible.  I have spent two hours Googling this and have tried a few things, which have not worked.

Comment: you'd need to add the "datepicker" class to your textbox, otherwise the jQuery won't work on it. And a label doesn't have an "onload" event as far as I know. Instead, just make the CheckDateField function run as soon as the DOM is ready using a jquery document.ready block

Comment: This selector `$(".datefield")` won't find any element in your current markup. Where are you setting the class `datefield` for the `input`?

Comment: Also, instead of checking for the feature `onload()`, do it within `$(function () { });`.

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bhwog7a9/ If this is what you're looking for, I can post an answer.

Comment: @melancia, yes please.  The JavaScript function does not complete because it says Modernizr was not found.  What script do I need to add for Modernizr? Is it this: bootstrap.js?

Comment: @ADyson, please see my comment above.  How do I find Modernizr? Thanks.

Comment: You need to include the `Modernizr` library just like you did with the others (ie: `jQuery`). https://modernizr.com/

Comment: Thanks.  I have installed it (via Library Manager) and it appears to work now.  I assume it is not part of the .NET Core 2.1 template?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with .NET Core yet, but I've posted an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code by just checking for the `HTML5 input date` feature when the page is loaded and acting accordingly.
Also, the selector you're using to grab the element won't work, as the `input` doesn't have a class `datefield` set.

Your generated markup would look similar to this:

```
<label for="dob">Date of birth</label>
<input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" class="datefield">
```

Note the lack of the `onload` event handler and that you set the `input type` to `date` to start with.

Your script bit to handle the `datepicker` should be similar to this:

```
// When the document is ready.
$(function () {
    // If input type date isn't supported.
    if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
        var el = $(".datefield");

        // In a single call (chained) set the input type to text
        // and attach the datepicker.
        el.prop("type", "text").datepicker();
    }
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bhwog7a9/)

Comment: Thanks.  This works+1.  Are there any implications of changing the class from 'form control' to 'datefield' on the server side as per your answer? +1.

Comment: You can change the selector to suit your needs. More here: [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors)

Comment: Thanks.  I have asked a follow on question here if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949847/using-the-html-5-datepicker-with-the-date-input-field